# Memory usage via Marketo REST API

Tags: python, rest, marketo

Marketo offers a REST API interface which can be used to bulk extract standard or custom obejcts. The REST API comes with limitation such as, memory usage per day (500 MB), more to find here: https://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/bulk-extract/#limits
The API offers a method the get the daily usage for users but only containing the number of API calls per day or over the last seven days.
The question is how to get the used memory per day. It is possible to see that information within Marketo itself but somehow I couldn't find a API method or implementation where this information is retrieved in some application.

Alternatively one could calculate the used memory based on the number of calls or something like that.
Here it would be really helpful if someone has an idea, maybe you faced something similar in the past.

Get the API call usage per for over the past seven days.
Used documentation:

- https://github.com/jepcastelein/marketo-rest-python
- https://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/endpoint-reference/lead-database-endpoint-reference/#/Usage/getDailyUsageUsingGET

Answer (score 0):

I recently dealt with an instance with a lot of API users and a bulk extract limit far in excess of 500mb that was never going to be hit.

The problem on the admin side was the lack of transparency and visibility into the who and how much, in terms of the bulk extract activities. It was dealt with by limiting the number of users with permissions to initiate bulk extracts via API.

With that, a process was eventually created such that all response data was documented and extract activities initiated on a predicable cadence.

In the end, only one such user was needed, since the extracts were being consumed by a database other users could access without the redundancies negatively impacting the performance of the instance (i.e. concurrency issues).

Resources:

- https://nation.marketo.com/t5/champion-program-blogs/marketo-api-and-recommended-best-practices/ba-p/324137
- https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/marketo/using/product-docs/administration/users-and-roles/export-roles-and-permissions.html
- https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/marketo/using/product-docs/administration/settings/bulk-export-api-information.html